# Why does my first picture have a dark area and the next is fine?

Tags: exposure, zoom, darkness, spots, mobile

[image]

[image]

I was in class and took a picture of the slides with my phone (iPhone 13 if that helps) but the first one (I zoomed in a little on that one) turned out as shown while the next one was fine. The two figures in front are probably my classmates sitting down but nobody was standing in the back so why are there blurry spots there and why did this happen when I’ve never had a problem with my pic before? I took more later and they were fine too. Thanks!

Comment: TV do not provide constant light, usually have 25/30 frames. If camera use speed which is faster you can catch the moment when the tv is dark. Also fluorescent light have similar circles (light/dark)

Comment: related: [Flicker Frequency for taking snapshot of monitor](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/114777), [Why does the camera output an image with multi-colors not shown by the naked eye under the projector?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/102268)

Comment: "...but nobody was standing in the back so why are there blurry spots there...?" Well, until a few days ago it was [ghost month](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_Festival) so all bets are off :-)

Answer (score 13):

This phenomenon entirely depends on how backlight of the LCD works. The brightness of LEDs is controlled with very frequent pulses (Pulse Width Modulation) which are mostly unnoticeable to humans. PWM works at fixed frequency and the duration of the pulse is what defines the brightness. Low PWM frequency is cheaper in production.

If your shutter speed is close to that pulse duration you will either get varying object brightness or even a completely dark screen.

The light being slightly visible on the edges is consequence of shutter acting gradually across the image (rolling shutter), so top and bottom of the screen were photographed at different moments.

You may observe similar phenomenon in other cases where LED lighting or gas discharge lamps are used.

Comment: This also is a problem when taking a picture with LED-based traffic lights in frame. On videos this becomes especially jarring, because the lights appear to flicker badly on the recorded video, completely misrepresenting the actual performance of the traffic light.

Comment: @Ruslan:  video should be shot at 1/50s, more than enough to oversample the PWM strobing.

Comment: @dandavis that's the frame rate, but not necessarily the exposure of each frame. In bright daytime conditions the exposure will likely be shorter.

Comment: @Ruslan well, I was speaking for a 24fps frame rate. If you shoot under 180 deg shutter angle (aka 2 X FPS), you get no motion blur and the video looks terrible and amateurish, like it came from a phone or camcorder; uncinematic.

Comment: @dandavis OK, I was talking about video shot by a phone (and also by dashboard cameras), where too often do I notice the flicker of traffic lights.